# For loop with two conditions reading variables

Tags: variables, unix, for-loop, environment-variables

For some reason the for loops below aren't iterating, any help appreciated.

I get the dat files generated but variables inside the sed aren't looping from for loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
input="/var/tmp/jay/apinfo"
host="/var/tmp/jay/hosts"
cat $input
cat $host
for inst in $(cat $input);do
for h in $(cat $host);do
sed -e "s/eb/$inst/g;s/alvcd/$h/g" env.dat > /var/tmp/jay/$inst.dat
done;done
```

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for correct practices from reading from files.

Comment: Beyond that -- right now, this code overwrites `$inst.dat` a whole bunch of times; the last value to be in `h` will always be the one that "wins", overwriting all prior values for that file. How best to fix that requires a description of your desired results that isn't really present; could you build a [mcve] someone could use to run the script themselves, and compare actual and desired results?

Comment: If you were writing to `$inst-$h.dat`, for example, then you'd actually have a separate output file for each combination; that would make a bit more sense.

Comment: Other potential bugs relate to the values having meaning to `sed` (for instance, `&0` will become not itself but will refer to the entire original string) -- but without knowing what your actual values look like, much of that is speculation. See [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021) for string-replacement practices that don't rely on `sed` and aren't subject to its limitations.

Comment: Here is snippet code with sed inside for not working. sed is unable to replace $i with i values, its unable to recognize the variable i.

for i in {3..9}; do sed -e 's/ap01/ap0$i/g'  ebr-ap0$i.dat; done

contents of file used in above for loop

more ebr-ap01.dat
base.node.name=ebr-ap01

Comment: You used double quotes in the question, and single quotes above; those are very different. Parameter expansions (like `$i`) don't occur in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It works now. Now Im trying to introduce one more parameter "j" in to the for loop. for loop is not liking that && So I have:

for [i in {3..9} && j in {9..11}]; do sed -e "s/ap01/ap0$i/g;s/a008/a00$j"  ebr-ap01.dat; done

more  ebr-ap01.dat
base.node.name=ebr-ap01
bio.listen.address=al-a008

Comment: Where did you get that syntax from? Square brackets are another name for the command called `test`, but they're just another command; they aren't special syntax, and can't be used to implicitly make a compound `for` loop. Anyhow, since you don't have any answers that would be invalidated, it's kosher to [edit] the question in a way that substantially changes its meaning -- but you should actually *edit the question*, not just extend it with comments.